# DataTemplate selection for singular content in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently you can use a DataTemplateSelector for Views that present lists of data like so:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewTest"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}"
                  ItemTemplate="{Binding TestItemTemplateSelector}" />
```

Currently, Xamarin do not provide a View which allows you to use a DataTemplateSelector for displaying singular items with varying properties. Is there any workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer at the following link by bmacombe which I found to be very helpful:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6052

ANSWER:

1. Create a custom control:

   ```
   public class ContentControl : ContentView
    {
        public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
        {
            get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ContentControl), propertyChanged: ItemTemplateChanged);

        public object Item
        {
            get => (object)GetValue(ItemProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemProperty, value);
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Item), typeof(object), typeof(ContentControl), null, propertyChanged: SourceChanged);

        private static void ItemTemplateChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = bindable as ContentControl;
            control.BuildItem();
        }

        private static void SourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = bindable as ContentControl;
            control.BuildItem();
        }

        public bool HideOnNullContent { get; set; } = false;

        protected void BuildItem()
        {
            if (Item == null)
            {
                Content = null;
                return;
            }

            //Create the content
            try
            {
                Content = CreateTemplateForItem(Item, ItemTemplate, false);
            }
            catch
            {
                Content = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (HideOnNullContent)
                    IsVisible = Content != null;
            }
        }

        public static View CreateTemplateForItem(object item, DataTemplate itemTemplate, bool createDefaultIfNoTemplate = true)
        {
            //Check to see if we have a template selector or just a template
            var templateToUse = itemTemplate is DataTemplateSelector templateSelector ? templateSelector.SelectTemplate(item, null) : itemTemplate;

            //If we still don't have a template, create a label
            if (templateToUse == null)
                return createDefaultIfNoTemplate ? new Label() { Text = item.ToString() } : null;

            //Create the content
            //If a view wasn't created, we can't use it, exit
            if (!(templateToUse.CreateContent() is View view)) return new Label() { Text = item.ToString() }; ;

            //Set the binding
            view.BindingContext = item;

            return view;
        }
    }
   ```
2. Create a DataTemplateSelector

   ```
   public class AlarmDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate DataTemplate1{ get; set; }
        public DataTemplate DataTemplate2 { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate DataTemplate3 { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate DataTemplate4 { get; set; }

        public AlarmDataTemplateSelector()
        {
            // Creating DataTemplates from ContentViews written in xaml
            DataTemplate1 = new DataTemplate(typeof(View1)); 
            DataTemplate2 = new DataTemplate(typeof(View2));
            DataTemplate3 = new DataTemplate(typeof(View3));
            DataTemplate4 = new DataTemplate(typeof(View4));
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a data template dependent on the selected alarm
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item"></param>
        /// <param name="container"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            var testItem = item as TestItem;

            switch (testItem.Type)
            {
                case Enums.AlarmType.None:
                    return null;

                case Enums.TestType.Test1:
                    return DataTemplate1;

                case Enums.TestType.Test2:
                    return DataTemplate2;

                case Enums.TestType.Test3:
                    return DataTemplate3;

                case Enums.TestType.Test4:
                    return DataTemplate4;

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. Add a reference to the control in your XAML page and implement the view:

   ```
   xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:TestProject.Views.Controls"

   <Controls:ContentControl x:Name="contentControlTest"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}"
                  ItemTemplate="{Binding TestItemTemplateSelector}" />
   ```