# Xamarin Forms - How to embed Content View on a page depending on the type of context

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

On WPF I did this. On Xamarin.Forms DataTemplate has no DataType attribute. Is it possible to do this with a DataTemplateSelector?

```
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}">
      <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AuthorizationContent}">
          <uc:AuthorizationUC/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RegistrationContent}">
          <uc:RegistrationUC/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AdminControlContent}">
          <uc:AdminControlPanel/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UserControlPanelContent}">
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Control panel" TextAlignment="Center" 
                       Margin="0,20"/>
            <uc:UserControlPanel/>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:QuestionsContent}">
          <uc:QuestionsUC/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it is for.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

Comment: Where do I need to bind the DataTemplateSelector?

<ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="RegisterUserTemplate">
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="UnRegisterUserTemplate">
            </DataTemplate>

            <dts:UserStateDataTemplateSelector x:Key="UserStateDataTemplateSelector"
                                               RegisterUser="{StaticResource RegisterUserTemplate}"
                                               UnRegisterUser="{StaticResource UnRegisterUserTemplate}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>

Comment: Please add that code to question. Its hard to read it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Using a DataTemplateSelector for a single content [is not implemented in Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6052). The comments in that issue describe custom code you could use.

OR see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64927676/199364, which builds on that code.

---

OR here is an alternative:

Make a collection with a single item. Bind to that collection. Then use selector with a collectionview (or any other layout that takes Items).

```xml
<ContentPage ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
    x:Class="MyNameSpace.MainPage"> 
    ...
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding OneContent}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <local:CustomDataTemplateSelector/>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

c#:

```cs
// Replace "BindableObject" with whatever base type your mvvm library uses. E.g. "BaseViewModel" or "MvxViewModel".
private ObservableCollection<BindableObject> _oneContent;
public ObservableCollection<BindableObject> OneContent
{
    get => _oneContent;
    set
    {
        _oneContent = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}


...
    var myContent = new ...;
    OneContent = new ObservableCollection<BindableObject>{ myContent };
```

Define your custom datatemplateselector - as described in [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector):

```cs
public partial class CustomDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    ...
}
```